# Is my model overfitted?

Tags: overfitting, text-classification

I am using a naive bayes classifier to classify 20 newsgroup dataset. My accuracy on the training set is 97 and on the testing set is 89. Is my model overfitted?
If it is what steps can I take to prevent overfitting. My code has an nlp preprocessing method, a pipeline that performs count vectorization , tdidf transformation and mulinomiall naive bayes.
Uses bigrams,max df=0.8, min df = 2. Alpha set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to determine if your model is overfit or not, on the information you provide. It is expected that the error on the validation set, is higher than on the test set. Have a look at the graph:

[image]

You can try hyperparameter tuning on the complexity of the model (regularization) - if you see even higher accuracy of the training set and a lower accuracy on the test set, it's an indication that the model is overfit and needs regularization.

shameless self promotion: I wrote a blog post about this (bias vs variance) [here](https://higgsino.medium.com/the-bias-variance-tradeoff-why-being-too-smart-is-dumb-446f2724671d).